# Limitar las entradas en los modelos.ForeignKey ()

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

¿Es posible limitar las entradas en models.ForeignKey() a una cantidad exacta?

Tengo un modelo llamado Tarjeta que pertenece a un Perfil, quiero que cada perfil pueda tener como máximo 2 tarjetas.

```
class Tarjeta(models.Model):
    perfil = models.OneToOneField(Perfil,on_delete=models.CASCADE) #limitado a 2
    email = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    titular = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
    direccion1 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    direccion2 = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    ciudad = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    pais = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    telefono = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo tienes tu modelo `Perfil`?

Comment: Con metodos propios de Django no, pero si es posible a traves de las vistas usando querysets que validen la cantidad de registros antes de almacenar datos